# Understanding Server/Client Routing: How Can Amazon(?) Be Redirecting My SPA ... Without a Redirect (or History Entry)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, react-router, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

**NOTE:** I'm providing details of my setup, but really this is a "how is this possible" question, not a "please debug my setup" question.

I have a "singe page application" (ie. an HTML file that uses the History API to simulate URLs).  I'm serving this app on AWS S3, behind an AWS Cloudfront ... front.

I had successfully configured things so that if someone went to `www.example.com/foo` (let's pretend I own `example.com`), Cloudfront would serve an "error page" of my `index.html`.  My `index.html` would then see the URL, and use its routing to show the user the correct page.

That all worked great ... until it didn't.  Now for some reason when I go to `www.example.com/foo`, I get redirected to `www.example.com`.  I'm trying to debug things, but what I can't understand is how I'm going from `/foo` to the main page.

When I look in the Network panel of my developer tools, I can see the request made to the original (`/foo`).  Then I can see the chain of requests (for images, css files, etc.), and they all have a referrer of `www.example.com/foo`.

Then all of the sudden I see a request for React Developer tools (why it needs to make a request is beyond me) ... and it's from referrer `www.example.com`.  After that I get one last image request from `/foo`, and then all subsequent requests come from `www.example.com`.

Can anyone explain how this could be working?  I know that if a server returns a redirect (either type) that could change my URL ... but every request has a 200 status (ie. no server redirects).

I know Javascript could "push" a new URL to my browser ... but that would leave a history entry right?  When I go "back" (either with my browser or `history.back()`) I go to the page before; I don't go "back" to `/foo`.

So somehow I'm not making a history entry, but I am switching my URL, and the URL I make requests from, and this all happens within milliseconds on page load ... without any redirects.  How?

P.S. When I use my dev tools to add an `beforeunload` breakpoint, then try to navigate from `example.com` to `example.com/foo` I *don't* hit that break point (either for going to `/foo`, or when I'm "redirected" back to `example.com`).

When I check the box for *any* Load event, I do see some happen ... *after* my URL has already switched.  In other words, I type `example.com/foo`, hit enter, and by the time any event fires I'm back on `example.com`.  Whatever mechanism is doing the "redirection" here ... it doesn't trigger *any* load events.

Comment: Just a wild guess: can you check if by any chance you deployed a dev version of the app?

Comment: I'm using Gatsby with a plugin to deploy to S3, so I only *can* deploy a built app .. I think. I do see a request for `webpack-runtime-3df70ac39eb3b89a09b7.js`, but I'm pretty sure that's just the built file Webpack makes, not some dev artifact.

Comment: P.S. Even if I did deploy a dev version ... I'm still trying to understand *how* (ie. the technical mechanism by which) a dev version could cause the behavior I'm describing .  Specifically, the URL changing during load, with no redirect responses, and no history entry from a client-side redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my (AWS-specific) problem, thanks to a bit of Gatsby documentation.  I'll include the details below in case it helps others, but I *won't* accept this answer, as I still don't understand *how* AWS did what it did (and I'd still welcome an answer for that).

What happened was that I had my Cloudfront "Origin Domain Name and Path" pointing to:

```
example.com.s3.amazonaws.com
```

However, as explained on https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/deploying-to-s3-cloudfront/:

> There are two ways that you can connect CloudFront to an S3 origin. The most obvious way, which the AWS Console will suggest, is to type the bucket name in the Origin Domain Name field. This sets up an S3 origin, and allows you to configure CloudFront to use IAM to access your bucket. Unfortunately, it also makes it impossible to perform serverside (301/302) redirects, and it also means that directory indexes (having index.html be served when someone tries to access a directory) will only work in the root directory. You might not initially notice these issues, because Gatsby’s clientside JavaScript compensates for the latter and plugins such as gatsby-plugin-meta-redirect can compensate for the former. But just because you can’t see these issues, doesn’t mean they won’t affect search engines.

> In order for all the features of your site to work correctly, you must instead use your S3 bucket’s Static Website Hosting Endpoint as the CloudFront origin. This does (sadly) mean that your bucket will have to be configured for public-read, because when CloudFront is using an S3 Static Website Hosting Endpoint address as the Origin, it’s incapable of authenticating via IAM.

Once I changed my Cloudfront "Origin Domain Name and Path" to the bucket's *static hosting URL*:

```
http://example.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Everything worked!

But again, I still don't understand *how* AWS did what it did when I mis-set my "Origin Domain Name and Path". It redirected me to my root domain, seemingly without either a redirect response OR a client-side redirect, and I'd love to hear how that was accomplished.